# How to calculate the tax basis for long term capital gain on an apartment building?

Tags: taxes

I wrote most in title, But here it is: what is the tax basis for long term capital gain for an apartment building?

- Bought in 89 for 500k.
- Sold in 14 for 1150k.
- Selling cost 50k.
- Depreciation 275k;
- Capital improvements 325k;

My way to get basis for capital gain tax is 1150 -50 -500 = 600k

Add depreciation 600 + 275 =  875

Deduct capital improvement 875-325 = 500k tax basis.

Comment: What is the tax jurisdiction?Tax law differs by country?

Comment: Why would your basis be amount realized minus selling costs minus purchase price?  Why would depreciation increase your basis but capitalized improvements drop your basis?  I'm not sure if I'm reading the calculations wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making six-figure improvements to property, you probably need to refer these questions to your regular accountant or tax adviser.

I'll provide general comments assuming you want to find your own basis for US income tax purposes.  A proper adviser is still the best route for actual determining your tax obligations.

Your basis generally is the price paid for the property (including debt assumed), provided you didn't engage in any tax moves that might change that assumption (e.g. a 1031 exchange).  So the starting number is the purchase price $500k.

The selling price and selling cost are not basis, though they will factor into your gain.

Your basis may be reduced by depreciation.  Depreciation deductions do not increase your tax basis, that would be double-dipping the expense.  Basis and deductions both reduce tax liability (at different times and in different ways) so you generally will not get the full use of both.  Depreciation deductions typically come at the cost of reducing basis.

Capital improvements may increase your basis if they are capitalized.  They will generally not go into basis if you deducted them at the time (e.g. some repair costs may be deductible in the year incurred).  As with depreciation, you don't get both deduction and basis for the same dollar; that is double-dipping.  Your capital improvements may have a different holding period that the rest of the property; if you made them in the last year, then that portion of the property might be short-term gain.

If you deducted all that depreciation (i.e. it's tax depreciation, not book depreciation) and you capitalized all the improvements, then your basis is $500k purchase price minus $275k depreciation deduction plus $325k capitalized improvements.  That's $550k basis, with those assumptions.

The amount realized was $1.15M minus $50k selling costs (if properly deductible), so that's a possible $550k gain above your adjusted basis.

However, this is a fact-based question, and various costs, insurance payments, and tax deductions may alter your adjusted basis.  An accountant or adviser could track all of these and also confirm the appropriate characterization (capital versus ordinary).

Comment: $550, I agree, with warning that $275K is 'recaptured depreciation.' Different taxes apply.